# confusing time newrelic graph

Tags: heroku, newrelic

[image]
In this graph left side graph which says web transaction graph it show seconds in Y-axis and maximum time approaching is 1750 ms which is 1.7 seconds while browser time shows 1.22s why is that . same goes on Apdex score graph, browser apdex score is 1.0 out of 7.0 which is great while if we see at the drawn graph it clearly shows that most of the requests lies in  0.5 - 0.75 seconds region so ain't apdex score should lie > 1.0 instead of sharp 1.0 seconds. I want to understand the graphs and times mentioned. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For:

> it show seconds in Y-axis and maximum time approaching is 1750 ms which is 1.7 seconds while browser time shows 1.22s why is that

At the point in time where the Web Transaction Time measures 1.7 seconds your throughput is 5+ individual transactions.  In addition, this is at the Overview (Application level), which could be across multiple different types of transactions.  You will not be able to compare this number to an individual browser transaction response time for these reasons.

For:

> apdex score should lie > 1.0 instead of sharp 1.0 seconds.

The unit of measurement of Apdex is not seconds.  See here for calculating an Apdex score: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/new-relic-apm/apdex/apdex-measuring-user-satisfaction#score

> Apdex score varies from 0 to 1, with 0 as the worst possible score (100% of response times were Frustrated), and 1 as the best possible score (100% of response times were Satisfied).

Answer (score 0):

> In this graph left side graph which says web transaction graph it show
>   seconds in Y-axis and maximum time approaching is 1750 ms which is 1.7
>   seconds while browser time shows 1.22s why is that?

You are in APM (stands for Application Performance Monitoring). This is your server-side code, from the looks of things I believe this is a Ruby on Rails application. The average time for the server side code is the 414ms. However since you also have the Browser Agent installed you see the average client side time, which is 1.22 seconds.  If you click on the APM bar in the upper left you can click over to Browser.

> same goes on Apdex score graph, browser apdex score is 1.0 out of 7.0
>   which is great while if we see at the drawn graph it clearly shows
>   that most of the requests lies in 0.5 - 0.75 seconds region so ain't
>   apdex score should lie > 1.0 instead of sharp 1.0 seconds. I want to
>   understand the graphs and times mentioned.

Again you are seeing both the Apdex Score for APM AND Browser. Your APM threshold is set at 0.5 seconds. This is the [0.5] above the graph. (Apdex is shown in brackets).

- Any transaction that comes in under 0.5 seconds receives a score of 1.
- Any transaction that comes in over 4X that threshold (so 4*0.5=2 seconds) receives a 0
- Any transaction that comes in between 0.5 and 2.0 seconds receives a 0.5

Add all of those up for each Transaction and divide by the number of "Requests Per Minute" (RPM) or number of Transactions for that time period. So for this overall time period you have an Apdex score of 0.78 (this will always be between 0 and 1).

The Browser threshold is [7.0] or 7 seconds. This is the default and can be configured to be lower.  For this time frame you have an Apdex score of 1.0, meaning that all transactions are under that 7 second threshold.